# how to make a subset of commands be conditional?

Tags: bash, shell-script, chef

I'm having issues finding a direct answer to my question, maybe because I don't know how to phrase it or the correct terms.

I'm looking to find out how to make a subset of commands in a chain be "either or"

as in

```
A && B && (C || D) && E && F
```

where the result of the previous command dictates if the next fires.

In this case it's a `chef` command

```
knife vault create
```

that causes the issue with a break error when trying to create a vault that already exists. So I want to do

```
knife vault update
```

if
`knife vault create` errors out of the script

Heres a bigger overview

```
command1 && \
command2 && \
(knife vault create
or
knife vault update) && \
command4 && \
continuing...
```

As there are so few cases (1) so far in the script I'm making I wanted to keep the formatting instead of suddenly beginning with `if`/`else` or something "more advanced".

Comment: Welcome to unix.SE ! If you are satisfied with any answer, such as the one below by @guest, do not forget that you can "accept" it by checking the "accepted answer" box left of the answer. A green check mark will appear, signalling to all users that your query has an answer and that presumably that answer is useful and worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
command1 &&
command2 &&
{ knife vault create ||
knife vault update; } &&
command4 &&
# ...
```

---

#### examples:

```bsh
echo command1 &&
echo command2 &&
{ echo knife vault create ||
echo knife vault update; } &&
echo command4 &&
exit
```

output:

```
command1
command2
knife vault create
command4
```

---

```bsh
echo command1 &&
false &&
{ echo knife vault create ||
echo knife vault update; } &&
echo command4 &&
exit
```

output:

```
command1
```

---

`if` satement:

```bsh
if echo command1 && false; then
    echo knife vault create ||
    echo knife vault update &&
    echo command4 &&
    exit
fi
```

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what i needed, only comment i have is that you missed "my case" of failure inside the "either or" but the essence gave me the info i needed to make it work. 100% correct, 99% correct for my use. Thanks a lot